# Как сделать больше задержку между fade in и fade out

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в css сделать задержку между анимациями дольше, то-есть я хочу чтоб текст который появляется, дольше оставался на странице, но чтоб его появление оставалось таким же резким как есть. Спасибо.

```css
/* animate text */

body {
  background: #000;
}

.sp-content h2 {
  font-size: 46px !important;
}

.sp-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sp-container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 1.5s ease-in backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 1.5s ease-in backwards;
  animation: blurFadeInOut 1.5s ease-in backwards;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
  font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -ms-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
}

.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
  -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 12s backwards;
  -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 12s backwards;
  -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 12s backwards;
  animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 12s backwards;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
}


/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  }
}


/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    -moz-transform: scale(5);
  }
}


/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    transform: scale(5);
  }
  20%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes blurFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInBack {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: scale(5);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sp-container">
    <div class="sp-content">
      <h2 class="frame-1">On-site vacuum processing</h2>
      <h2 class="frame-2">Unit capacity adjustment</h2>
      <h2 class="frame-3">Remote operation</h2>
      <h2 class="frame-4">Customized filtration fineness</h2>
      <h2 class="frame-5">Recyclable filter media</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: пример не рабочий в отличии от codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну дак вам необходимо просто взять коэффициент (я взял 3) и увеличить все delay в это количество раз, продолжительность в это количество раз. А в самих анимациях у вас указаны этапы анимации, ну вот собственно начальный и конечный этап (появление и исчезновение) сократить в это количество раз - т.е. в моем случае я 20% поделил на 3 (взял 7, для ровного счета), а время исчезновения сделал таким же как и появление т.е. 100%-7%. Если нужно как и было соотношение времени появления к времени исчезновения, то считайте как `(100 - (100-75)/coeff)%`

```css
/* animate text */
body {
  background: #000;
}
.sp-content h2 {
    font-size: 46px !important;
}
.sp-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 line-height: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 font-size: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 9s ease-in backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 9s ease-in backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 9s ease-in backwards;
 animation: blurFadeInOut 9s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
 animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
 animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
 font-size: 200px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 27s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 27s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 27s;
 animation-delay: 27s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
 -webkit-animation: none;
 -moz-animation: none;
 -ms-animation: none;
 animation: none;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5  {
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 36s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 36s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 36s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 0.4s ease-in 36s backwards;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
}


/**/
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 7%,93%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 }
}

/**/
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 7%,93%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
 }
}

/**/
@keyframes blurFadeInOut{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  transform: scale(5);
 }
 7%,93%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack{
 0%{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
 50%{
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: scale(2);
 }
 100%{
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: scale(5);
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="sp-container">
<div class="sp-content">
<h2 class="frame-1">On-site vacuum processing</h2>
<h2 class="frame-2">Unit capacity adjustment</h2>
<h2 class="frame-3">Remote operation</h2>
<h2 class="frame-4">Customized filtration fineness</h2>
<h2 class="frame-5">Recyclable filter media</h2>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо блоьшое.

Comment: @АлександрПивень если вы считаете что ответ корректен, то вам необходимо нажать на галочку под репутацией ответа, т.е. выбрать его как "Верный". Ну а благодарность можете выражать "стрелочкой вверх" в репутации ответа. Это так, небольшой "мануал" по работе в сообществе SO ^_^